# Android: Get all id and path from specify folder in MediaStore managedQuery

Tags: android, sd-card, mediastore

**UPDATE Logcat and Java Code.**

Hi I want to get all image id,full path from specify folder on sd-card.
this my code.

```
private void Gallery() {

    ImageList = new ArrayList<GalleryDetail>();

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    Cursor image_cursor;
    image_cursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,  null,
            new String[] {currentDir.toString()}, null);


    if (image_cursor != null) {
        while (image_cursor.moveToNext()) {

            GalleryDetail img = new GalleryDetail();

            String image_id = image_cursor.getString(image_cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));

            String image_path = image_cursor.getString(image_cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

            Log.e("get Path.", image_path);

            img.setImageId(image_id);
            img.setImagePath(image_path);
            ImageList.add(img);
        }

        // List of file path 
        FilePathStrings = new String[ImageList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ImageList.size(); i++) {
            FilePathStrings[i] = ImageList.get(i).getImagePath();

        }

    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me and log cat show this message to me.

> 09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2475a8
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1644)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity.Gallery(GalleryActivity.java:166)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity.access$0(GalleryActivity.java:159)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity$LoadGallery.doInBackground(GalleryActivity.java:85)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.mimi.ngsbusproject.GalleryActivity$LoadGallery.doInBackground(GalleryActivity.java:1)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   09-11 11:17:21.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     ... 4 more

Please help.How can I solve this problem?

Sorry for my very bad language skill.Thank in Advance :)

Comment: Where do you initialize `ImageList`?

Comment: post your logcat here..at which line getting nullPointer

Comment: Hi,sorry I forget copy to show you. now I'm edited.

Answer (score 1):

**Have added this permission in mainfest.xml?**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

UPDATE

```
ArrayList<String> mFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
          File mDirectory;
         String folderPath = "/mnt/sdcard/download";
         mDirectory = new File(folderPath);

            // Get the files in the directory
            File[] files = mDirectory.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File f : files) {

                    mFiles.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }

            }
```

UPDATE

Recursive function to getAll images

```
private ArrayList<String> allImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] extensions = { "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "JPG", "PNG", "JPEG" };

    private void loadAllImages(String rootFolder) {

        File file = new File(rootFolder);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    if (f.isDirectory()) {
                        loadAllImages(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                            if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(extensions[i])) {
                                allImages.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

UPDATE To fetch gallery images

```
private String[] arrPath;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private int ids[];
    private int count;

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

    Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, new String[] {"%myimagesfolder%"}, orderBy); //UPDATE HERE

    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    count = imagecursor.getCount();
    arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Missing permissions do not throw a `NPE`. A security exception would have been thrown in that case.

Comment: And could you please lay off `bolding` all of your text? Refer here: [Link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174583/stack-overflow-question-formatting-guidelines-bold-italics).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.So if I want to get all file image.How can I do that?

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia Yep,But if you have other code please tell me.Because I want to use code like my current(use MediaStore). :D

Comment: @Biraj Zalavadia  Thanks for your edited.But I want to know how to use MediaStore with specify folder like "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures"? Thank in advance :)

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Now I updated code and logcat in my question.Please help me to solve about this.What code I missed?